# Button as a Link

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, linkbutton

I want to know what is the difference between both codes , the first isn't working while the second is working properly , so what causes this .Help appreciated.

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <button> Next </button>
</a>

<button>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"> 
    Next Page
  </a>
</button>
```

Comment: You have not added any codes.

Comment: @SaboorElahi I didn't know I'm not allowed to embed pictures yet, now I have added I hope you can help , thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are invalid. HTML does not allow links to contain buttons or vice versa.

The error handling routines in browsers are just different for the two cases.

If you want a link that looks like a button then use a link and apply CSS.

Comment: well I'm still learning HTML so I don't know CSS yet or JS, but the second code worked well and is doing the Job properly , I just want to know why the first didn't work while the second did. I'm just trying to do the best with  my current knowledge.

Comment: "but the second code worked well" — Correction: **seems** to work well.

Comment: "why the first didn't work while the second did" — See the second paragraph of this answer.

Comment: I got your point , so for a person that only knows HTML for know the second case is enough and doing the job in my case? but in general both are not proper in coding , true? and thanks for help anyways .

Comment: @Dash — No, since you are depending on the error recovery features of *every* browser to act the same. In your case, as someone who does not know the language for influencing the way webpages look, you should just not worry about the way the page looks and write valid, semantic HTML (resulting in you having a link that looks like a link).